# How to undo automatic label on Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Somehow I accidentally put a label on all outgoing mail in Gmail and now I can't figure out how to undo it so it doesn't automatically label everything.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a filter that's applying the label.

It probably looks something like

```
Matches: from:(youremailaddress@gmail.com)
Do this: Apply label "outgoing-label"
```

*or*

```
Matches: to:*
Do this: Apply label "outgoing-label"
```

Just look for the label that's getting applied and delete that filter. Filters are found under "Settings".

This assumes, of course, you're using regular Gmail and not Google Apps Email